# Native linking error: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am working on `Xamarin.Forms` Version 3.4. I am executing iOS project from windows machine(As my visual studio connected to Mac machine).

iOS project showing few errors saying

> Native linking error: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
>
> Native linking failed, duplicate symbol: '_main'
>
> Native linking failed. Please review the build log

This is the screenshot for all errors

[image]

Comment: First try to clear the build cache on the mac by deleting the build folder for your app. You can run the following command in Terminal  to do this: `rm -rf /Users/gsps/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/FCMPush.iOS`.  If that does not work, did you add anything to the iOS project beyond what is created by default?

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT - I have added firebase notification's googleJson file. After after adding  `--registrar:static` attribute, issue got fixed. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue solved by adding `--registrar:static` in iOS Build's *Additional mtouch arguments*.